# How to use a custom function to solve a linear programming optimization problem

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I need to use `linprog` for an optimization (`minimize` takes far too much RAM), but I need to add a relatively complex constraint that can't be represented by a matrix. Is there a way to use `minimize` with a `linprog`-like solver that doesn't use a large amount of memory? Or is there a way to implement a custom function within linprog?

Here's an example of what I would like to do:

```
# inequality constraint
cons = lambda x: sum(x) - 1000
bounds = [(0, 1) for _ in enumerate(solution_length)
coefficients = # coefficients here

results = scipy.optimize.minimize(coefficients, cons=({"ineq": cons},), bounds = bounds)
```

or use scipy minimize with a matrix of size 10,000,000+ for a linear problem without solving with a nonlinear method.

Where should I start?

Comment: What is the complex constraint that can't be represented by a matrix? The constraint shown in the post is easily represented with a matrix with one row, a column for each decision variable, and all entries 1.0.

Comment: for more context on the issue, you can look at this .txt file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r02RlR6ESaJ9db4QeBq1LnBYlEc8cITn/view?usp=sharing. However I do think that the problem needs to be solved with a linear function.

Comment: Also, the solution to this problem appears to be as simple as finding the decision variables with the lowest coefficients.

Comment: @MattHaberland You're right. It would be as simple as sorting the coefficients and finding the lowest one. I'm not looking for a solution for this problem but a way to implement a custom constraint with a linear solver.

Comment: There is no way of using `scipy.optimize.linprog` or `scipy.optimize.milp` with a custom callable. I know because I wrote `milp` and have been the primary maintainer of `linprog` in recent years. If you think your problem is linear, please describe the actual problem in the post and we can recommend how to represent it in the form required by the solvers. The link you posted in the comments doesn't have the appropriate permissions set for others to view.

Comment: @MattHaberland just fixed permissions. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256987/discussion-between-matt-haberland-and-lwhitenack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the author of the functions, @MattHaberland, mentioned, there is no way to implement a custom callable within `linprog` or `milp`. I was eventually able to reimplement multiple iterations of `linprog` to solve my problem (thanks @NickODell), but if a function *absolutely* needs a custom callable, `minimize` is your best bet.

For more information on solving complex linear programming problems, here is a Wikipedia article on one of the most fundamental problems, the travelling salesman: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem